# regex parse multiple expressions

Tags: regex, splunk

I have a requirement to parse  part of url with multiple expressions using regex, expressions are like /abc/def (or) /z/a (or) /v/g. I have a regex that satisfies single expression, but not sure how to do for multiple expression.

```
(?<volga>.+?\/abc\/def.+?)
```

volga is a named capturing group.
Above regular expression satisfies anything before /abc and anything after /def, the same way url also has /z/a and /v/g. This is kind of either /abc/def/ or /z/a or /v/g can exist in url. How to write a regular expression that checks for all of above expressions.

Examples of url:

```
/api/com/abc/def/710660716/847170/
```

```
/api/com/z/a/
```

Comment: Using Spl queries regex in splunk.

Comment: Do you know the regex OR: '|' Try inserting that in your regex.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought you were looking for multiple matches, not matching multiple patterns.

Comment: ```| rex field=requestPath "(?<volga>.+?(\/abc\/def) | (\/z\/a) | (\/v\/g.+?)"```, Is this regular expression okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
(?<volga>.+?\/((abc\/def)|(z\/a)|(v\/g)).*)
```

- Matches any string containing

  - abc/def
  - or z/a
  - or v/g

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7uVYSi/1)